# Can I make shortcut XeLaTeX from WinEdt 9.0 ?

Tags: winedt

I want make  shortcut to easy use it at WinEdt 9.0 editor, Let's  make shortcut XeLaTeX like PDFTeXify (SHIFT + CTRL + P) or Compile (F9). But Not only shortcut XeLaTeX, can LuaLaTeX, PDFTeX, PDFLaTeX, or TeX

Comment: Do you have the plug-in LaTeXify installed?

Comment: @karlkoeller , Yes, I have plug -in LaTeXify installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to "Options" -> "Options Interface" and double-click the "Main Menu" item:

[image]

A local copy of `MainMenu.ini` gets opened. In this file, substitute the lines

```
    ITEM="PDFLaTeX"
      CAPTION="PDF&LaTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXPDFLaTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\PDFLaTeX.edt');"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
    ITEM="PDFTeX"
      CAPTION="PDF&TeX"
      IMAGE="TeXPDFTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\PDFTeX.edt');"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
    ITEM="-"
    ITEM="LuaLaTeX"
      CAPTION="LuaLaTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXLuaLaTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\LuaLaTeX.edt');"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
    ITEM="LuaTeX"
      CAPTION="LuaTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXLuaTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\LuaTeX.edt');"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
    ITEM="-"
    ITEM="XeLaTeX"
      CAPTION="XeLaTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXXeLaTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\XeLaTeX.edt');"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
    ITEM="XeTeX"
      CAPTION="XeTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXXeTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\XeTeX.edt');"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
```

with the following

```
    ITEM="PDFLaTeX"
      CAPTION="PDF&LaTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXPDFLaTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\PDFLaTeX.edt');"
      SHORTCUT="41040::Shift+Alt+P"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
    ITEM="PDFTeX"
      CAPTION="PDF&TeX"
      IMAGE="TeXPDFTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\PDFTeX.edt');"
      SHORTCUT="57424::Shift+Ctrl+Alt+P"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
    ITEM="-"
    ITEM="LuaLaTeX"
      CAPTION="LuaLaTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXLuaLaTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\LuaLaTeX.edt');"
      SHORTCUT="41045::Shift+Alt+U"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
    ITEM="LuaTeX"
      CAPTION="LuaTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXLuaTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\LuaTeX.edt');"
      SHORTCUT="57429::Shift+Ctrl+Alt+U"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
    ITEM="-"
    ITEM="XeLaTeX"
      CAPTION="XeLaTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXXeLaTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\XeLaTeX.edt');"
      SHORTCUT="41029::Shift+Alt+E"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
    ITEM="XeTeX"
      CAPTION="XeTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXXeTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      SHORTCUT="57413::Shift+Ctrl+Alt+E"
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\XeTeX.edt');"
      REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
```

At this point press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

Now you have the following shortcuts

- PDFLaTeX: <kbd>Shift+Alt+P</kbd>
- PDFTeX:   <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+Alt+P</kbd>
- XeLaTeX:  <kbd>Shift+Alt+E</kbd>
- XeTeX:    <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+Alt+E</kbd>
- LuaLaTeX: <kbd>Shift+Alt+U</kbd>
- LuaTeX:   <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+Alt+U</kbd>